# Rudin proof: closed subsets of compact sets are compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I'm reading (self-study) Rudin's mathematical analysis book and I'm going through the proof of the following theorem (theorem 2.35 p38):

> Closed subsets of compact sets are compact

I will now write out my proof, so can someone verify whether I filled in the details correctly? (so in general, is every step I made valid, are the explanations correct etc. Any questions to test my understanding will be appreciated as well.

**Proof** (edit): Assume $F \subset K \subset X$ with $F$ closed and $K$ compact. Let $\{V_a\}$ be an open cover of $F$. Then $F \subset \bigcup_a V_a$. We prove that there is a finite subcover of $F$, from which compactness will follow.

Consider the union $\{V_a\}\cup \{F^c\} := V$. We prove that this is an open cover of $K$. Any set in the collection $\{V_a\}$ is open, by hypothesis that this is an open cover of $F$, and $F^c$ is open, since $F$ is closed. So every set in this collection is open. Since $X = F \cup F^c \subset V \cup F^c$, it follows that $K \subset V \cup F^c $ (as $K \subset X$) and this proves that the union written above is an open cover of $K$.

Because $K$ is compact, it follows that there is a finite collection $\Omega \subset V$ which is a subcover of $K$, so $K \subset \bigcup_{A \in \Omega} A$, and because $F \subset K$, it also follows that $F \subset \bigcup_{A \in \Omega} A$.

Now, if $F^c \notin \Omega$, then $\Omega = \{V_{a_1}, \dots, V_{a_n}\}$ for open sets $V_{a_1}, \dots, V_{a_n}$, which is a finite subcover of $F$, since $F \subset \bigcup_{A \in \Omega} A$. Otherwise, if $F^c \in \Omega$, then $\Omega = \{F^c, V_{a_1}, \dots, V_{a_m}\}$, but $F \cap F^c = \emptyset$, so $F \subset V_{a_1}\cup \dots \cup V_{a_n}$, such that $\Omega - \{F^c\}$ is a finite subcover of $F$.

QED

Comment: You can shorten your proof that $C=\{V_a\}_a \cup \{F^c\}$ is an  open cover of $X$ by noting that $C$ is (obviously) an open family, and that  $\cup C=(\cup_aV_a)\cup F^c \supset  F\cup F^c=X.$

Comment: Isn't this what I prove?

Comment: Yes you did. With more words. But there's nothing wrong with your work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a mistake:

> so we obtain an open cover $K^c \cup V$ of $K$, and because $K$ is compact

You don't **know** that $K$ is compact. You are trying to **prove** that $K$ is compact. You only know that $K$ is closed and $F$ is compact. In fact, the mere fact that you don't use $F$ anywhere in your proof should be cause for alarm.

---

Also, you are confusing **covers** (which are collections of sets) with their coverage (i.e., union of their component sets).

So, when you write that you take a finite subcover $\Omega$ of $K$, you then say that $K\subset \Omega$, which is not true. What is true is that $$K\subset\bigcup_{A\in\Omega} A$$ which is different!

---

I advise you to restart the proof again, and here's a couple points to start you off:

- You need to prove that $K$ is compact
- That means you need to prove every open cover of $K$ has a finite subcover
- That means you take some cover, $\mathcal V$, such that $K$ is covered by $\mathcal V$ (you were on point until here).
- Now you need to prove there exists a finite subcover of $\mathcal V$.

And a little hint:

- You know $F$ is compact, so any open cover of $F$ has a finite subcover.
- Can you add one more set to $\mathcal V$ such that the resulting cover will be a cover for $F$?

---

**Aftert your edit:**

You still have that misstake of cover vs coverage. So, instead of saying that $K^c\cup V$ is an open cover of $F$, you should say that $\{K^c\}\cup \{V_a\}$ is an open cover of $F$.

I am even more concerned that I think you are confused a bit about what an open cover is. When you say

> Now, consider the union $K^c \cup V$. Since $K \subset V$, it follows that $X =K^c \cup K \subset K^c \cup V$, meaning that $X = K^c \cup V$, so $F \subset K^c \cup V$ and $X$ is an open subset of itself

I'm thinking "yes, all he said is true, but it's irrelevant".

An open cover is a **collection of open sets**, not **a collection of sets whose union is open**. So, you don't need to prove that $$K^c\cup V$$ is open (even though it **is**), you need to prove that **every element of** $$\{K^c\}\cup\{V_a\}$$ is open (which is not hard, it's just that if you don't do that, the proof is incorrect).

Comment: I corrected the proof. Is it correct now? (don't look at my misunderstanding of open cover/open coverage, thank you for pointing that out though!)

Comment: @Math_QED I added an explanation into my answer.

Comment: Your answer and edits made me realise a lot of mistakes. Thank you for that.

Comment: @Math_QED That's why we're here :)

Comment: I edited the proof for the last time. Can you look at it again please? I hope I did not make any mistakes now. I'm sorry I can't upvote your post twice, but there are other ways of compensating this, as you might have noticed.

Comment: @Math_QED It looks much much better. Well done!