# Are only the closed subspaces of a compact space compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-vector-spaces, compactification

I have read a [Wikipedia article about Stone-Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) and have a question about one particular sentence:

"... $[0, 1]^C$ is compact since $[0, 1]$ is. Consequently, the closure of $X$ in $[0, 1]^C$ is a compactification of $X$."

Does that imply that generally, if a space A is compact, then any closure of a topological space in the A is also compact? So the **closure** is what is important and open subspace of compact space wouldn´t have to be compact?

Do yu have any examples of open subspaces of compact spaces, s.t. the subspaces are not compact?
Thank you.

Comment: The fact that we use the closure of $X$ ensures $X$ is *dense* in this closure (the *smallest* closed superset of $X$), which is part of the definition of a compactification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $X$ is compact and $A \subseteq X$ then $\overline{A}=\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ is a closed subset of a compact space and these are always compact in the subspace topology, as is classic.

If $X$ is Hausdorff and $A \subseteq X$ is compact in the subspace topology, then $A$ is closed in $X$; this is also classical. So in $[0,1]^C$ (which is compact and Hausdorff) closed and compact subsets are the same.

In general, an arbitrary (non-closed) subspace of a compact space need not be compact, e.g. the open subspace $(0,1)$ of the compact $[0,1]$ is not compact (but homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first question is yes. You can find that here: [closed subset is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2365108/rudin-proof-closed-subsets-of-compact-sets-are-compact)

Second has a counter example: Take $A=[0,1]$ and $S=(0,1)$. $ S\subseteq A$ is open. Show that it is not compact.